# sqlite com android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

ja esta resolvido.
Eu quero adicionar 3 dados(data, local, e preco) na minha base de dados. ja resolvia alguns erros na implementação da base de dados. mas agora aparece me este erro. nao sou muito bom a me expressar sobre este tema, pelo o motivo de tar a aprender agora e sozinho. 
Tenho um erro na linha 41 `(AddHistoria.addRegisto(new HistoricoCompras(data, local, preco));)` em que aparece este erro `("addhistorico in AddHistorico cannot be aplied to (.com.example.a13731.ganhemais.historico de compras)")` na minha `activity` inserir.

Isto é o minha activity inserir(adiciona):

```
package com.example.a13731.ganhemais;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class adiciona extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText edData,edLocal, edPreco;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_adiciona);

Intent intent = getIntent();
final String value1 = intent.getStringExtra("key1");
final String value2 = intent.getStringExtra("key2");

edData = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_data);
edLocal = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_local);
edPreco = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_preco);

}

public void inserirCompra(View v) {
AlertDialog.Builder dialogo = new AlertDialog.Builder(adiciona.this);
dialogo.setTitle("Aviso");
dialogo.setMessage("Inserir aluno?");
dialogo.setNegativeButton("Não", null);
dialogo.setPositiveButton("Sim", new
DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
String data = edData.getText().toString();
String local = edLocal.getText().toString();
String preco = edPreco.getText().toString();
AddHistoria.addRHistorico(new HistoricoCompras(data, local, preco));
AlertDialog.Builder d = new AlertDialog.Builder(adiciona.this);
d.setTitle("Aviso");
d.setMessage("Registo inserido!");
d.setNeutralButton("OK", null);
d.show();
edData.getText().clear();
edLocal.getText().clear();
edPreco.getText().clear();
}
});


}
```

A minha class (HistoricoCompras):

```
package com.example.a13731.ganhemais;

import java.io.Serializable;

/**
* Created by a13731 on 05/06/2017.
*/

public class HistoricoCompras implements Serializable {
private static String data;
private static String local;
private static String preco;
public HistoricoCompras(String data,String local,String preco)
{
this.data=data;
this.local=local;
this.preco=preco;
}
public void setdata(String data) {
this.data = data;
}
public void setlocal(String local) {
this.local = local;
}
public void setpreco(String preco) {
this.preco = preco;
}

public static String getData() {
return data;
}
public static String getLocal() {
return local;
}
public static String getPreco() {
return preco;
}
}
```

minha base de dados (DBhistorico):

```
package com.example.a13731.ganhemais; /**
* Created by a13731 on 05/06/2017.
*/
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DBhistorico extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
// Database Version
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
// Database Name
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "GanheMais";
// table name
private static final String TABLE_historia = "Historia";
// Shops Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_Data = "data";
private static final String KEY_local = "local";
private static final String KEY_Preco = "preco";
public DBhistorico(Context context) {
super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
String CREATE_historia_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_historia + "(" + KEY_Data + " TEXT,"
+ KEY_local + " TEXT, " + KEY_Preco + "Text" + ")";
db.execSQL(CREATE_historia_TABLE);
}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
// Drop older table if existed
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_historia);
// Creating tables again
onCreate(db);
}

// Adding new shop
public void addCompra(HistoricoCompras Historia) {
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(KEY_Data, HistoricoCompras.getData());
values.put(KEY_local, HistoricoCompras.getLocal());
values.put(KEY_Preco, HistoricoCompras.getPreco());
// Inserting Row
db.insert(TABLE_historia, null, values);
db.close(); // Closing database connection
}
}
isto cria uma array(ADDhISTORIA):
package com.example.a13731.ganhemais;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
* Created by a13731 on 05/06/2017.
*/

public final class AddHistoria {


private static ArrayList<Historico> aHistorico = new ArrayList<Historico>();

/*private addHistoria()
{
aHistorico = new ArrayList<Registo>();
}
*/
public static void addRHistorico(Historico r)
{ aHistorico.add(r); }
}
```

Comment: Olá Rafael, tente descrever melhor o problema o que você já tentou para resolver, e o que você pretende com o código, ajudaria quem for te ajudar.

Comment: eu quero adicionar 3 dados(data, local, e preco) na minha base de dados. ja resolvia alguns erros na implementação da base de dados. mas agora aparece me este erro. nao sou muito bom a me expressar sobre este tema, pelo o motivo de tar a aprender agora e sozinho.

Comment: Ok, sem problemas, vai adicionando essas informações a sua pergunta, é so ir em [editar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/210257/edit) e colocar mais infromações, caso alguém te pedir mais informações você vai adicionado a sua pergunta.